# Error when I try to access the state property with riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, state-management

Please help! I'm using riverpod with the redo and undo buttons in my app, but keep getting "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void"
I exhausted all my options. Find my code below(Ln 58 -71):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

   final drawingAreaProvider =
       StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<DrawingAreaNotifier, List<Offset>>((ref) {
     return DrawingAreaNotifier();
   });

   final redoProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<void>((ref) {});
   final undoProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<void>((ref) {});
   final toggleGridProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) => false);

   class DrawingAreaNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Offset>> {
     DrawingAreaNotifier() : super([]);

     void addPoint(Offset point) {
       state = [...state, point];
     }

     void clearPoints() {
       state = [];
     }
   }

   class DrawingArea extends ConsumerWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
       final points = ref.watch(drawingAreaProvider);

       return GestureDetector(
         onPanStart: (details) {
           final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
           final localPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
           ref.read(drawingAreaProvider.notifier).addPoint(localPosition);
         },
         onPanUpdate: (details) {
           final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
           final localPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
           ref.read(drawingAreaProvider.notifier).addPoint(localPosition);
         },
         onPanEnd: (_) {
           // Do nothing on pan end
         },
         child: Stack(
           children: [
             CustomPaint(
               painter: DrawingPainter(points),
               size: Size.infinite,
             ),
             Positioned(
               top: 20,
               left: 20,
               child: Row(
                 children: [
                   IconButton(
                     icon: const Icon(Icons.undo),
                     onPressed: () {
                       ref.read(undoProvider).state;
                     },
                   ),
                   IconButton(
                     icon: Icon(Icons.redo),
                     onPressed: () {
                       ref.read(redoProvider).state;
                     },
                   ),
                   IconButton(
                     icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on),
                     onPressed: () {
                       ref.read(toggleGridProvider).state =
                           !ref.read(toggleGridProvider).state;
                     },
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }
   }

   class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
     final List<Offset> points;

     DrawingPainter(this.points);

     @override
     void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
       final paint = Paint()
         ..color = Colors.black
         ..strokeWidth = 2
         ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

       if (points.isEmpty) return;

       final path = Path();
       path.moveTo(points.first.dx, points.first.dy);
       for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      path.lineTo(points[i].dx, points[i].dy);
       }

       canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

       final crossPaint = Paint()
         ..color = Colors.red
         ..strokeWidth = 2;

       for (final point in points) {
         canvas.drawLine(Offset(point.dx - 5, point.dy),
             Offset(point.dx + 5, point.dy), crossPaint);
         canvas.drawLine(Offset(point.dx, point.dy - 5),
            Offset(point.dx, point.dy + 5), crossPaint);
       }
     }

     @override
     bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
       return true;
     }
   }
```

I tried to update these providers to use the correct syntax for initializing the state.

```
   final redoProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<void>((ref) => null);
   final undoProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<void>((ref) => null);
   final toggleGridProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) => false);
```

Still didn't help

Comment: Please provide more info on what are you trying to achieve when pressing those buttons.  I will update my answer base on that. It is not clear, and your "redoProvider" and "undoProvider" are just empty providers that cannot do anythin.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to build a drawing app. So when a user draws or taps on the screen, I need a point to appear on the screen. I was trying to update the polygondrawer widget and also add the functionality to be able to undo, redo and toggle on grid.

Comment: undo button, ref.watch(undoProvider).state is called when the button is pressed. This will retrieve the current state of the undo provider and trigger any updates in the UI that depend on this state.
redo button, ref.watch(redoProvider).state is called when the button is pressed to retrieve and trigger updates based on the redo provider's state.
grid snapping button, ref.watch(toggleGridProvider).state = !ref.watch(toggleGridProvider).state is called to toggle the state of the grid snapping provider when the button is pressed.
This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: If you are just calling `ref.read(myCustomProvider)` or `ref.watch(myCustomProvider)` and you are not doing anything else inside you buttons callback functions (opTap, onPressed, ...) then your buttons are not doing anything. They are just getting the provided values and thats it

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that your code throws an error. [As indicated in the "state" property of StateNotifier](https://pub.dev/documentation/state_notifier/latest/state_notifier/StateNotifier/state.html) it is `@protected` and `@visibleForTesting`, which implies that it can only be accessed from child classes and test.

As recommended by the Riverpod documentation, if you want to reactively get a provided value, i.e. rebuild you widgets on changes of the provider, you shall use "watch" instead of "read".

```dart
final value = ref.watch(myCustomStateProvider);
```

On the other hand, if you want to get the provided value "on-demand", for example within a callback function of a button, then you shall use "read".

```dart
...
onTap: () {
     final value = ref.read(myCustomStateProvider);
     // Do something with the provided value...
  },
...
```

Note that both **"watch" and "read" can only be used to get the value/state provided by the provider**.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to fix that and see how it goes.